# Reason for automatic RAID Resync

Tags: linux, raid

I have a server that peforms a resync for its software raid in undefined intervals. This results in massive load and I am forced to stop all services until the resync is complete (20+ hours). What could be the reason for an automatic resync?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some cases, cron.  On RedHat-derived boxes, check for the existence of a file like `/etc/cron.weekly/99-raid-check`; on other distros, it can be a file in the `/etc/cron.d/` directory.

**Edit** following your question: a check is not the same as a resync.  A check compares the two halves of a RAID-1 array and updates `/sys/block/mdX/md/mismatch_cnt` with the current count of differences between the two halves.  But it requires reading every single bit of both halves of the mirror, and is thus **hugely** IO-intensive (well, input-intensive).

If you find the mismatch count is non-zero, you can then choose to force a resync.  Your system's script may do that for you as part of the service, I can't comment, but there is a difference between a check and a resync.  Both are hugely IO-intensive, though, and result in the sort of performance issues you describe.

Comment: It's a debian box. I found /etc/cron.d/mdadm, In it stands `57 0 * * 0 root [ -x /usr/share/mdadm/checkarray ] && [ $(date +\%d) -le 7 ] && /usr/share/mdadm/checkarray --cron --all --quiet` Does a check automatically result in a resync?

Comment: @Philip, see the comment in that file.  It runs a resync the first sudany of every month.  That file is a script so you could easily look at it.  Also see its configuration file `/etc/default/mdadm`.